# running mpi subroutine in fortran program

Tags: fortran, mpi

I want to run a Fortran program which calls a subroutine that I want to parallelize with MPI.  I know this sounds complicated, but I want to be able to specify the number of processes for each call.  What I would want to use is a structure like this:

```
program my_program

implicit none

!Define variables

nprocs =  !formula for calculating number of processes.

call my_subroutine(output,nprocs,other input vars)

end my_program
```

I want to run my_subroutine with the same effect as this:

```
mpirun -n nprocs my_subroutine.o
```

where my_subroutine has been compiled with 'other input vars.'

Is this possible?

---

Here is a simple example.  I try compiling as follows:
$ mpif90 -o my_program WAVE_2D_FP_TUNER_mpi.f90 randgen.f SIMPLE_ROUTINE.f90
I try to run it like this:
$ mpirun -np (1 or 2) my_program

---

```
PROGRAM WAVE_2D_FP_TUNER_mpi
USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL(KIND=8) :: T,PARAM(1:3),Z,ZBQLU01
REAL(KIND=8) :: ERRORS,COSTS,CMAX,CMAX_V(1:1000),THRESHOLD,Z_MIN,Z_MAX
REAL(KIND=8) :: U,S,R(1:6),MATRIX(1:15)
INTEGER :: EN,INC,I,J,M,P
INTEGER :: NPROCS,IERR

!0.8,-0.4,0.4,10,4,4,7 -- [0.003,0.534]
!0.8,-0.2,0.2,10,4,4,7 -- [0.190,0.588]
CALL MPI_INIT(IERR)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,NPROCS,IERR)

THRESHOLD = 0.D0
EN = 81
INC = 1
Z_MIN = -2.D-1; Z_MAX = 2.D-1

T = 1.D0
PARAM(1) = 10.D0; PARAM(2) = 4.D0; PARAM(3) = 4.D0

CMAX = 7.D0 !Max that wave speed could possibly be.

CALL ZBQLINI(0.D0)

OPEN(UNIT = 1, FILE = "TUNER_F.txt")
WRITE(1,*) 'Grid Size: '
WRITE(1,*) T/(EN-1)

DO P = 1,15
    S = 0
    Z = Z_MIN + (1.d0/(15-1))*dble((P-1))*(Z_MAX - Z_MIN)
    WRITE(1,*) 'Z: ',Z
    DO I = 1,1000
        DO J = 1,6
            R(J) = ZBQLU01(0.D0)
        END DO
        !CALL PDE_WAVE_F_mpi(T,PARAM,R,Z,CMAX,EN,INC,NPROCS,U)
        CALL SIMPLE_ROUTINE(T,PARAM,R,Z,CMAX,EN,INC,NPROCS,U)
        IF (U<=threshold) THEN
        S = S + 1.D0
        ELSE 
        S = S + 0.D0
        END IF
    END DO
    MATRIX(P) = (1.D0/1000)*S
END DO

DO I = 1,15
    WRITE(1,*) MATRIX(I)
END DO

PRINT *,MINVAL(MATRIX)
PRINT *,MAXVAL(MATRIX)

CLOSE(1)

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)

END PROGRAM WAVE_2D_FP_TUNER_mpi
```

---

Here is the subroutine that I wish to parallelize with mpi.

---

```
SUBROUTINE SIMPLE_ROUTINE(T,PARAM,R,Z,CMAX,EN,INC,NPROCS,U)
! Outputs scalar U = T*Z*CMAX*INC*SUM(PARAM)*SUM(R)*SUM(Y)
USE MPI

IMPLICIT NONE

REAL(KIND=8), INTENT(IN) :: T,PARAM(1:3),R(1:6),Z,CMAX
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: EN,INC
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: NPROCS
REAL(KIND=8), INTENT(OUT) :: U
REAL(KIND=8) :: H,LOCAL_SUM,SUM_OF_X
REAL(KIND=8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: X
INTEGER :: PX,PX_MAX,NXL,REMX,IX_OFF,P_LEFT,P_RIGHT
INTEGER :: J
INTEGER :: IERR,MYID

! Broadcast nprocs handle to all processes in MPRI_COMM_WORLD
CALL MPI_BCAST(&NPROCS, NPROCS, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
! Create subcommunicator SUBCOMM  (Do not know how to define WORLD_GROUP?)
CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,WORLD_GROUP,SUBCOMM,IERR)
! Assign IDs to processes in SUBCOMM
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(SUBCOMM,MYID,IERR)
! Give NPROCS - 1 to SUBCOMM
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(SUBCOMM,NPROCS-1,IERR)

H = 2.D0/(EN-1)

! LABEL THE PROCESSES FROM 1 TO PX_MAX.
PX = MYID + 1
PX_MAX = NPROCS
! SPLIT UP THE GRID IN THE X-DIRECTION.
NXL = EN/PX_MAX !nxl = 10/3 = 3
REMX = EN-NXL*PX_MAX !remx = 10-3*3 = 1
IF (PX .LE. REMX) THEN !for px = 1,nxl = 3
    NXL = NXL+1 !nxl = 4
    IX_OFF = (PX-1)*NXL !ix_off = 0
ELSE
    IX_OFF = REMX*(NXL+1)+(PX-(REMX+1))*NXL !for px = 2 and px = 3, ix_off = 1*(3+1)+(2-(1+1))*3 = 4, ix_off = 1*(3+1)+(3-(1+1))*3 = 7
END IF

! ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR VARIOUS ARRAYS.
ALLOCATE(X(0:NXL+1))
X(:) = (/(-1.D0+DBLE(J-1+IX_OFF)*H, J=1,EN)/)
LOCAL_SUM = SUM(X(1:NXL))
CALL MPI_REDUCE(LOCAL_SUM,SUM_OF_X,1,&
          MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,&
          0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)

U = T*Z*CMAX*INC*SUM(PARAM)*SUM(R)*SUM_OF_X

DEALLOCATE(X)

CALL MPI_COMM_FREE(SUBCOMM,IERR)

CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)

END SUBROUTINE SIMPLE_ROUTINE
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to change the number of processors used in the subroutine, where I want nprocs to be calculated from the value of EN.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need this? I bet you do not.

Comment: What you want is really strange. It would be natural for threads, but not for MPI. Giles' answer below is completely correct.

Comment: I don't think what I'm trying to do is strange.  I'm ultimately trying to solve a pde with different grid refinements determined by the value of EN.  I want to increase the number of processors working on the pde solver based on the value of EN during runtime.  This should prevent the code from slowing down a lot for very fine grid size, right?

Comment: It isn't how MPI is normally used. Isn't the total number of running processes fixed by the number of cpu's anyway?

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to start the MPI app with the maximum number of processes.

Then `my_subroutine` will first `MPI_Bcast(&nprocs, ...)` and `MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ..., &subcomm)` in order to create a sub communicator `subcomm` with `nprocs`
(you can use `MPI_UNDEFINED` so the "other" communicator will be `MPI_COMM_NULL`.

Then the MPI tasks that are part of `subcomm` will perform the computation.

Finally, `MPI_Comm_free(&subcomm)` and `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)`

From a performance point of view, note sub-communicator creation can be expensive, but hopefully not significant compared to the computation time.
If not, you'd rather revamp your algorithm so it can have `nprocs` tasks do the job, and the other ones waiting.

An other approach would be to start your app with one MPI task, `MPI_Comm_spawn()` `nprocs-1` tasks, merge the inter-communicator, perform the computation, and terminates the spawned tasks.
The overhead of task creation is way more important, and this might not be fully supported by your resource manager, so I would not advise this option.

Comment: Ok.  Let me think about this.  But how can I control what nprocs is?

Comment: What do you mean? Don’t you have a formula that computes it ? If you mean the number of tasks to start with `mpirun`, then it should be the max of what your formula will return.

Comment: This solution is the correct answer to the question asked. I wonder if the OP actually knows what they are asking for, though...

Comment: I guess I'm confused because I don't want to start with the max number of processes.  For example, I want to run my_subroutine a few thousand times with nprocs = 1, then with nprocs = 2, then with nprocs = 4,8,16,etc.  Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: I understand your requirement. That would require `MPI_Comm_spawn()` but I would advise against that at first. The MPI way is to always start 4 tasks, and have 1 working/3 waiting, then 2 working/2 waiting, ... or simply invoke `mpirun` 4 times with different task counts. I fully understand this is not intuitive at first glance, but this is how I recommend you to use MPI.

Comment: Ok.  Would you mind showing a short pseudo-code of what you mean, with a program and subroutine?  I get the concept of what you're saying.  But I don't know how to translate this into code.  I need to see what it looks like to start a communicator with nprocs and then use a subset of these to handle a subroutine while the other wait.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I'd rather do it the other way around : do your homework/research and if/when you are stuck, edit your question with a [MCVE] and clearly describe your issue. Meanwhile, `man MPI_Comm_split` is a good start.

Comment: Ok.  What I'm going to do is post my actual code for the outer program I'm using.  You will notice that in the code I normally try to call a PDE solver that takes in a vector R of random numbers.  The random number generator, randgen.f, contains the function ZBQLU01, which generates pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 1.  To make the code shorter, I replaced the PDE subroutine with the subroutine SIMPLE_ROUTINE.  What I do in here is try to split up a vector, X, among different processes.  Please let me know if you have questions, and what you suggest I change.  It works for np = 1, not np>1.

Comment: Hi Gilles.  I just edited simple_routine to try to use what you were saying about mpi_comm_split.  Does it make sense?  Anything you see that's wrong with the syntax?  Thanks.